# Protractor debug configuration in IntelliJ

Tags: typescript, debugging, intellij-idea, protractor

I've been trying to setup a node JS run/debug configuration in IntelliJ to run my protractor tests. At first, I've been getting the following error upon debugging(note: run works flawlessly)

```
    Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
15:37:45] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:37:45] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[15:37:45] I/BlockingProxy - Starting BlockingProxy with args: --fork,--seleniumAddress,http://localhost:4444/wd/hub,--logDir,bp-logs,--highlightDelay,80
[15:37:45] E/BlockingProxy - Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:65281 failed: address already in use
[15:37:45] E/BlockingProxy - Exited with 12
[15:37:45] E/BlockingProxy - signal null
[15:37:45] E/launcher - Error: Error: BP exited with 12
    at ChildProcess.bpProcess.on.on.on (C:\.............)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
[15:37:45] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Basically after some reasearch I figured I need to add the --inspect=0 parameter to the node parameters, so that debugging happens on a free port, and it worked, but now when I debug it doesn't actually start the execution. It just says that the debugger is attached, but nothing else.

Has anyone else had any issues with hanging debugger / child processes ports etc. when debugging protractor?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using node.js run configuration? Did you try using [protractor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/protractor.html#ws_protractor_running) configuration instead?

Comment: Hi, yes I have :( And there is an error which says that "Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:49878 failed: address already in use". So my way to work-around it from what I have read is to run it through node.js and pass --inspect=0, which should make sure only open ports are used.

Comment: I'm not aware of such issues using protractor, so this must be smth specific to your setup... "address already in use" is usually thrown when forking child process without execargv specified - in such cases, child process uses the execargv of the parent, thus the problem occurs... But I don't have such problems when debugging protractor, so it must have taken care of it...

Comment: Yes, in fact I was able to breakpoint at bprunner, apparently it is where the blocking proxy is being started - as a forked child process. This is where it's inspect is given the same port... I haven't figured out how to fix this and whether the issue is coming from project configurqtions. I tried disabling blocking proxy by passing use blocking proxy=false in the config but it didn't work

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/4398 should fix the issue, but it's not yet accepted afaik...

Comment: @lena Thank you so much, this actually fixes the issue! Wonder why the pull request hasn't been accepted.